# how can i use a namespace string with jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables, javascript-namespaces

I have the following code example...

```
$.pg = {
width : 700,
height: 200,
rate: 30
    };
```

Is there a convenient way I can write $.pg[width], rather than $.pg['width'] all the time to get 700?  The whole point of me putting width, height and rate into pg, is so I can write less.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to write even less, you could have it `$.pg = { w: 700...` and then just do `$.pg.w`

Comment: Note that this isn't really a jQuery issue, it's a JavaScript syntax issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.pg.width
$.pg.height
$.pg.rate
```

to refer to those properties.  If the property name is known at code writing time (like it is here), then you can use either the dot syntax `.propName` or `["propName"]` but as you've noticed, the dot syntax is shorter.  If the property name is not known at code writing time (and thus is stored in a variable), then you have to use the `[variableName]` syntax.